# Position content in ExpansionPanelSummary [React Material-UI]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image: Goal]

I think the image makes it clear enough, I have two ExpansionPanelSummary components, I'd like to move the icons in the first one to the right next to the ExpandMoreIcon. I've been thinking of using CSS pseudo-selectors to achieve this but nothing so far. There might even be a much simpler solution than that though. My code right now is:

```
 <ExpansionPanelSummary ... />
   <Typography variant="h6">Devices</Typography>

   <div ...>
     <IconButton>
       <FilterListIcon  style={{ color: grey[700] }}/>
     </IconButton>
     <IconButton>
       <SearchIcon  style={{ color: grey[700] }}/>
     </IconButton>
   </div>

</ExpansionPanelSummary>
```

*Note:* I haven't added any styling to the div, the ExpansionPanelSummary has attributes irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can flex property in your child nodes in `ExpansionPanelSummary` like this below.

```html
<ExpansionPanelSummary>
   <Typography variant="h6" style={{flexGrow: 1}}>Devices</Typography>

   <div>
     <IconButton>
       <FilterListIcon  style={{ color: grey[700] }}/>
     </IconButton>
     <IconButton>
       <SearchIcon  style={{ color: grey[700] }}/>
     </IconButton>
   </div>

</ExpansionPanelSummary>
```

Comment:  wow, I didn't know about flexGrow. I don't really understand it, though. Can you explain what it's doing exactly?

Comment: You can check it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) it gives detailed explanation

Comment: oh okay, i think my problem was with thinking the flexGrow goes to the parent tag and then the number is for the nth child tag, if that makes sense xD 

Thanks anyway though, appreciate it!